# "Next" button in ionic

Tags: ionic2

I have many input fields in the form and I want to move to next input if user press "Go" button on keyboard. I found cordova-plugin-keyboard and ionic-plugin-keyboard plugins for this, but I don't know how to implement the functionality exactly. 
If you have any other solution for this problem, please share. I am using IONIC3.
Thanks

```
<input round class="input-container font_style" maxlength="50" placeholder="Email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

Comment: Unfortnaly we can not do this in this time, but we have some little hack for this! For example you can set a handler for enter (Go key on keyboard) and this handler focused on next element

Comment: I have handler for "Go" button, but don't know how to set focus on next ion-input. I have used this for setting focus @ViewChild('input') myInput ;                      setTimeout(() => {
        this.myInput.setFocus();
      },150); but its not working

Comment: Use this.myInput.focus()

Comment: You could use the directive from this Ionic forum post: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-go-to-the-next-input-field-instead-of-submitting-the-form/59422/29

I am having some issues with the scrolling on large forms using focus next in general though (using that directive and other methods). Ionic is really a pain to use for large forms in general.